# How to break relationships database when change to microservice

Tags: sql, node.js, microservices

In monolithic application I have a sample database like this

```
User
id:  serial
name : string
password :string 
..
Blog
id : serial
body : string
author_id : Int
```

When I want to get a list of posts with author info, I simply make inner join query. If I change my system to microservice. Blog and User are independent services. They will have an own database.
Should I  add author_id column on blog database?
If blog database don't have author_id, how can I get a list of post with author info?
I really need an example of microservices in Nodejs

Comment: I have the same questions...hope any expert answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add author_id column on blog database. But you shouldn't add foreign key.

If you want to get list of posts with related user information, you should use API Gateway pattern. API Gateway is a linking element for all microservices. This element make requests to microservices and then merge responses programmatically.

For example, you can use this function for merge responses:

```
function(a, b, select) {
  var m = a.length, n = b.length, c = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    var x = a[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) { // all combinations
      var y = select(x, b[j]);  // filter out the rows and columns you want
      if (y) c.push(y);         // if a row is returned add it to the table
    }
  }

  return c;
}
```

Moreover, you can find turnkey solutions for API Gateway.